# Make tongue and groove on table saw versus router

Tags: joinery, power-tools

I have some finish carpenters joining hardwood panels together with tongue and groove joints. They have access to a basic cast iron router table, heavy duty Bosch router, and high-quality tongue and groove shaper bits. However, they prefer to do the work on the table saw.

They say they get more repeatable results from the table saw. They say it is hard to control the height of the router bit and it can vary slightly from run to run, and it is hard to recover the exact correct height when changing bits. With the table saw they do a fence adjustment, which they claim is easier and more reliable than trying to set the height on the router bit.

Is this preference for the table saw reasonable or is there a reason why the router should be preferred?

Note that all the joints are along the sides of the boards. There are no end joints.

Comment: Your finish carpenters do not have their own tools?

Comment: Does it really matter how your carpenters do the work so long as it's done well and the finish meets your standards? It's like complaining that a framing carpenter is hitting a nail 5 times with a 16oz hammer instead of 3 times with a 32oz hammer - who cares so long as the nail is properly sunk?

Comment: @FreeMan Well, it is information for me if I want to do similar work myself. If the table saw is good, then I will try that, but if a router is preferable, then I focus on a router. From the answer below it appears a router is only preferable if I have an accurate microadjustment, which my current table does not have.

Comment: Then I'd suggest putting that info in the question so people know how to address it. As it stands, it looks (to many of us) as though you're questioning their work.

Comment: @FreeMan What does it matter who the personalities are, I am asking about what tool to use for what job.

Comment: Op - The answer given does not state that a router with micro adjustment is preferable, only that it would be just as good as a table saw.  The word 'preferable' is not used at all in the answer.  So far, you are the only person looking for a reason for the router to be 'preferable'.

Comment: T&G joints don't have to be perfect because the typical reason to use them is when laying out a "panel" that you don't necessarily intend to glue because you want to allow for expansion. In this case, any tool will work. Is this joinery for gluing up, or something else? Honestly, if this is for gluing up a hardwood panel don't bother with T&G or anything. Maybe dowels or biscuits for helping keep things lined up, but clamped and glued edge grain is nice and strong. To be answerable, we need to know the application.

Answer (score 3):

I've done both and they're both fine.  A router lift and a fence with micro-adjust will get you results just as good as a table saw.  If they're working with a cheaper router base mounted under a board style router table and a clamp-down fence it'll be a pain though.

Like most things in woodworking, there's more than one way to do this effectively.  Personally my favorite is to use a slot-cutter on a router table.  That way you don't have to stand anything up on edge.  But if they're more comfortable with the table saw I wouldn't second-guess them.  In general it's frustrating to be micromanaged.